# How to pass multiple insert queries into MySql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure in MySQL and I want to pass a string of multiple insert queries

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_stringQry`(IN qry varchar(500))<br>
BEGIN <br>
    SET @input = qry; <br>
    PREPARE stmt FROM @input; <br>
    EXECUTE stmt;<br>
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;<br>
END
```

When I pass a single query it works but when I pass two or more queries it gives an error
Example:

```
call test.test_stringQry("INSERT INTO `test`.`products`(`pro_name`,`pro_price`) VALUES('test',900.00);INSERT INTO `test`.`products`(`pro_name`,`pro_price`) VALUES('test',900.00)")
```

Comment: What specific queries did you pass in?

Comment: Insert queries: call test.test_stringQry("INSERT INTO `test`.`products`(`pro_name`,`pro_price`) VALUES('test',900.00);INSERT INTO `test`.`products`(`pro_name`,`pro_price`) VALUES('test',900.00)")

Comment: You can execute only one statement in a prepared statement.